# What could come next?

Tags: word

Trebrehs
Sgubmuh
Sellitsap
Ycrep
Ecirouqil
Smug

What could come next?

Hint:

> The Queen’s makeup mirror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be:

> Tnim Slairepmi

Because:

> The words are sweets written backwards, so my answer is Mint Imperials